# How to compare the following values in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I wants to compare the following values using jquery.

```
  var bsversion = 4.4.0 ;

  if(bsversion < 5.0.0){

            jqueryurl = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' + jsversion + '/jquery.min.js';
        
    }
```

Why I am not able to access if statement?

Comment: You could `parseFloat(bsversion)` and  `parseFloat('5.0.0')` (which evaluate to 5)

Comment: Can't be possible without using parseFloat ?

Comment: Yes you can - `'4.4.0' < '5.0.0'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove All dots`.`

Convert String to integer. then compare:

```js
var bsversion = "4.4.0" ;
  if(parseInt(bsversion.replace(/\./g,"")) < parseInt("5.0.0".replace(/\./g,""))){

        //jqueryurl = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/' + jsversion"/+ '/jquery.min.js';
        console.log("less than 5.0.0");
    
}
```